# Unprotect not working in excel add in online office365

Tags: office-js, excel-addins

We are using the api sheet.unprotect(password) function to unprotect a workheet, it has been working fine, but now it throws error with the latest office-js library. The issue only happens in the browser for the online excel(office365), my installed office365 works fine, I have reproduced this isue in Script Lab as well. Attach the screen image below.

[unprotect worksheet error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktoiv.png)

Comment: I can reproduce. I'll see if I can get some help.

Comment: Microsoft has confirmed that this is a bug. I'll report back when its fixed. I recommend that you create an issue at the [office-js repo](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues). You'll be able to interact with the engineers directly there instead of having me as a middleman.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this to Microsoft, I have created issue for them on GitHub as you suggested.